# CardView showing greyscreen in preview?

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-cardview

My Cardview showing greyscreen. Can i know what the reason of these problem?

I have tried invalidate cache and restart but its not working

This is my cardView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my preview
[image]

Comment: It shows only in the Android studio preview. Did you try running your code on a device or an emulator?

Comment: Yes i have try running it and it force close on my device

Comment: Probably you are having some other issue. Can you check logs (logcat), and see what exception is getting thrown after your app crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a careless mistakes actually i forgot to add implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0' in my gradle(app).